# How to swap x-axis and y-axis in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there any option to swap the x-axis and y-axis on button click. 
swap means changing x-axis to y-axis and y-axis to x-axis. all the data will be same. converting column chart to bar chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortnately you need to destroy and create new chart.

Answer (score 3):

What about the inverted property (set it to true to flip everything for the axes). See API docs: [Highcharts API reference: Inverted](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted)

Comment: took a long time to find this to figure out how to switch axis without messing up labels and things. nice one.